# get date Intervals in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

how can I do the equivalent of `interval '12' month` from SQL like in `date_parse(due_date, '%Y%m%d')- interval '12' month` in pyspark? (my pyspark code is below)

```
 (df1.join(df2, ['a', 'b'], how='left')
        .filter(F.col('date1') < F.col('date2'))
        .filter(F.col('date1') > F.col('date2') - interval '12' month)
        .groupby(['a','b']).count()
        .cache())
```

in the above code `date1` and `date2` are both cast `to_date`.

Comment: are date1 and date2 columns' entries datetime objects?

Comment: I have cast them using F.to_date('date1', 'yyyyMMdd').alias('date1'). so they look like 'yyyyMMdd'. When you .show() they come up as example:  2017-10-13

Comment: can you show us dummy data for df1&df2 and your expected results? would be easy to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (df1.join(df2, ['a', 'b'], how='left')
        .filter(F.col('date1') < F.col('date2'))
        .filter(F.months_between(F.col('date2'), F.col('date1'))  < 12 )
        .groupby(['a','b']).count()
        .cache())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
(df1.join(df2, ['a', 'b'], how='left')
        .filter(F.col('date1') < F.col('date2'))
        .filter(F.col('date1') > F.col('date2') + relativedelta(months=-12))
        .groupby(['a','b']).count()
        .cache())
```

Comment: I get the following error : AttributeError: 'relativedelta' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'